# Better way to convert const wchar_t * to const std::basic_string<char_t>

Tags: c++, c++11

I am wondering if there is easier way (less verbose) to convert `const char_t*` to `std::string_t` rather than below:

```
typedef wchar_t  char_t;
typedef basic_string<char_t> string_t;

std::wstring ws(script_->GetName());  //GetName() returns const char_t*
const std::string wsStr(ws.begin(), ws.end());
const string_t script_name(wsStr.begin(), wsStr.end());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
#ifdef OS_WIN
#include <tchar.h>
typedef wchar_t  char_t;
#define CHAR_WIDE
#else
typedef char char_t;
```

Comment: `typedef wchar_t  char_t;` Are you sure about that?

Comment: see the edit pls...

Comment: What are you trying to do? To convert `std::string` to `std::wstring` you should use `std::iconv`

Comment: @NulledPointer I want above code to be less verbose. that's all.

Comment: There is no `std::string_t`

Comment: @M.M read the question carefully.

Comment: @H'H There is no such thing as `std::string_t`, therefore there is no way to convert anything to a nonexistent type

Comment: @M.M thanks for noticing that. If you read question CAREFULLY, you will see I mean std::string_t  == std::basic_string<char_t>

Comment: @H'H I read the question and nowhere does it say "std::string_t == std::basic_string<char_t> " or anything that means that.  Your `string_t` typedef is not related to `std::string_t` (if there was such a thing, which there isn't).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124850/discussion-between-hh-and-m-m).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `typedef`s that you have, it boils down that you want to convert a `wchar_t const*` string to a `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`. You could just pass the range of the `wchar_t const*` string into the constructor of `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`:

```
wchar_t const *str = L"abcdefgh";
const std::basic_string<wchar_t> script_name(str, str + std::char_traits<wchar_t>::length(str));
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70ab2777a23dde09)

Answer (score 3):

You've got three common situations:

1. the `wchar_t*` must point to ASCII only values, and you want a `std::string` in ASCII.
2. the `wchar_t*` may point to non-ASCII character and you want a `std::string` with wide characters
3. the `wchar_t*` may point to non-ASCII characters and you want a `std::string` in UTF-8.

Generally situation 3 is the best as least likely to cause problems elsewhere in the program. But it's also the hardest to handle, as you need to provide your own routines for converting the wide chars to UTF-8. There are plenty of C++ source files available for that job on the web.

For 1:

```
std::string answer;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    answer.push_back( (char) wcharptr[i]);
```

For 2, the same code, but you need to template answer with the wide type you want, and obviously remove the `char` cast. That's where life gets difficult,and why can be undesirable, because if not careful you end up with lots of `std::string`s with different types.

For 3:

```
std::string answer;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
   char utf8[8];
   int Nutf8;
   int ii;

   Nutf8 = widetoutf8(utf8, wcharptr[i]);
   for(ii=0;ii<Nutf8;ii++)
      answer.push_back(utf8[ii]);      
}
```

And you must provide `widetoutf8()` or an equivalent.